# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple Visual Studio 2017 15.8 node js project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I have installed vs2017 15.8. If I open a console C# app it opens fine. However trying to open node js project throws the following error. Has anyone managed to solve it?

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867434/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-valuetuple)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I could solve the problem by installing "**.NET Framework 4.7.2**"

Install-Source: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/4054530/microsoft-net-framework-4-7-2-offline-installer-for-windows

After the Installation i have rebooted my System.

Comment: Please show the process of installing **".NET Framework 4.7.2"** so that other readers can also know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and as suggested by mc-hollin the **installation of 4.7.2 worked** for me as well.

Please see the installation steps below:

1. Open this link : https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net472

   *If the above link does not work please go to https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-framework-runtime and proceed from there by selecting the correct framework.*
2. This will initiate the downloading of **NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe** in your system
3. Once the downloading has finished, please start the installation by double clicking the exe and let the installation begin. This could take a while based on the speed of your internet connection.
4. A restart after the installation is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to the other answers.

Remove System.valuetuple from references. Otherwise it doesn't work and I do not know why. Basically valuetuple is already in 4.7.2 and so if you use visual studio 2019 you're all set.

[image]