# System.ValueTuple cannot find the file specified Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Winform GUI that works fine on my windows 10 machine.  When I try to run it on a Windows 2003 server machine I get the following:

> 'Could not load file or assembly "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am using .net 4 since it works on server 2003.  The GUI loads fine just some part of the functionality triggers this error.  How to fix this issue?

Comment: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867434/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-valuetuple)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Value tuples are only available starting from .NET Framework 4.7 and above.**

See the [Applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0#applies-to) section in the docs:

> .NET Framework    4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8

But you're out luck, .NET Framework 4.7 [lowest supported server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55167) is **2008 R2 SP1**:

> Supported Operating System
>
> Windows 10
>
> Windows 7 Service Pack 1
>
> Windows 8.1
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
>
> Windows Server 2012
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> Windows Server 2016

Comment: System.Value Tuple can be downloaded as nuget package for earlier Frameworks but still should be at least 4.5. I assume that one is also not supported on 2003

Comment: You are right, the requirements for 4.5 are the same for servers: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: that's weid because the Target framework for my project is ".NET Framework 4" but they still let me use it without giving me error

Comment: One thing is the Framework you target, another the run-time Framework. E.g., if you have .Net 4.8 installed, your app targeting .Net Framework 4.0 will run on 4.8.