# Error BC31091: Import of type 'ValueTuple(Of ,)' from assembly or module 'CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary' failed in VS2022 but works in VS2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, valuetuple

I have a .NET Framework 4.6.2 Microsoft Test project that throws the error:

```
error BC31091: Import of type 'ValueTuple(Of ,)' from assembly or module 'CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary' failed.
```

When is compiled in VS2022 (Version 17.7.6) but works when is compiled in VS2019 (Version 16.11.26).

I tried everything in [Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867434/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-valuetuple) and in [Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple´2´ is not defined or imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382971/predefined-type-system-valuetuple%C2%B42%C2%B4-is-not-defined-or-imported) to make it work in VS2022 but has been unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly,  ValueTuple on .NET Framework is usually *just not worth it* - there are some severe assembly binding problems; do you *actually need* value-tuple? and more to the point: do you *actually need* to be using .NET Framework? and 4.6.2 in particular? There *have* been a series of bugs to glitches like this: they're called *later versions of .NET Framework* - so: 4.8 - but if possible, .NET "current" (i.e. .NET 7, nearly .NET 8 at time of writing) is the recommendation

Comment: @MarcGravell We have been using ValueTuples for a long time and we didn't have problems until now. The project is in .NET Framework because it has dependencies (like WebForms) of legacy libraries (like VFP provider) and it's difficult to migrate it to .NET Core (unfortunately). And the question is... why it works in VS2019 and not in VS2022?